# Hive Python UDF

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, hive-udf

I am using this Python UDF script:

```
import sys
import collections 
import datetime
import re

try:
    for line in sys.stdin: 
        line=line.strip()
        number,sd=line.split('\t')
        sd=sd.lower()
        sd=sd.split(' ')
        new_sd_list=collections.OrderedDict(collections.Counter(sd))
        new_sd=' '.join(new_sd_list)
        print('\t'.join([str(number),str(new_sd])))
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

While executing in Putty The below command.

```
SELECT TRANSFORM(number,shortdescription) USING 'python name.py' \
   AS (number,shortdescription) FROM table;
```

I am getting this error:

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"number": "ABC00548","shortdescription":""Master data inconsistency check in India Optimizer."}
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
> MapReduce Jobs Launched:
> Stage-Stage-1: Map: 4   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
> Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

Comment: Add the table DDL and a data sample

Comment: DDL:

number:string
shortdescription:string

sample data:
"number":"ABC0003888"
"shortdescription":"Clean up location name database used for Agricast weather page in DRUPAL and Historical Weather page in DRUPAL"

Comment: `ABC00548`does not seem to be a number

Comment: Its a string.. all the fileds in the table are string 

I think the error may be because of unicode in short description as there are cases where short description are like 'EXTRAPRÁTICA - SEAC'

can this occure , if so how to correct it

Comment: Once again, please add the table DDL (`show create table ..`) and a data sample (~10 rows)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `hv_snw_incidents_restapi_stg`(
  `number` string,
  `shortdescription` string)

INC000001      create: Refresh_ A2R Service Delivery Dashboard
 
INC000002     create: Refresh_ SBS Dashboard - Territory KPI

INC000003      EXTRAPRÁTICA - SEAC

Comment: Please add it to your original post

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import collections 
import datetime
import re

try:
    for line in sys.stdin: 
        line=line.strip()
        number,sd=line.split('\t')
        sd=sd.lower()
        sd=sd.split(' ')
        new_sd_list=collections.OrderedDict(collections.Counter(sd))
        new_sd=' '.join(new_sd_list)
        print('\t'.join([str(number),str(new_sd)])) #syntax error
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
```